# Updating an atomic variable with a non atomic and vice versa

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, stdthread, stdatomic

I am updating an atomic variable size_t using from one thread and reading it from another. Following is the code:

**Code:**

```
// MyClass.hpp
#pragma once
#include <atomic>

class MyClass {
public:
    size_t GetVal() {
        return m_atomic_val;
    }

    void SetVal(const std::size_t val) {
        m_atomic_val = val;
    }

private:
    std::atomic<size_t> m_atomic_val{0};
};


// main.cpp
#include "MyClass.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    MyClass obj;
    obj.SetVal(4);

    std::thread my_thread = std::thread([&obj]{
       std::cout << "Thread started" << std::endl;
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30));
        obj.SetVal(8);
    });

   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
   auto val = obj.GetVal();
   std::cout << "The value is: " << val << std::endl;
   my_thread.join();
}
```

**Question:**

- But as you can see, I am updating `m_atomic_val` which is a `std::atomic<size_t>` with a `size_t` which is non atomic. Will this have bad repercussions? Is this illegal?
- The return type of `GetVal` is `size_t` but its returning a `std::atomic<size_t>`. Is this wrong?
- So, my primary quesion is that is mixing of atomic and non atomic variables allowed the way I am doing in the sample code?
- This is only a simple example to demonstrate the question I have. What if there was one writer thread and one reader thread which are running concurrently and race conditions are very likely? Should I switch to using mutexes instead of atomics?

**Environment:**
My code runs on iOS, Android and macOS.

Comment: For the first part, you have the statement `m_atomic_val = val;`. Would you still wonder about this if you instead had `m_atomic_val = 8;`?

Comment: If it was `m_atomic_val = 8`, then I wouldn't really worry about it. I get your point. So, `std::atomic<size_t> = size_t` doesn't really matter. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D) to an atomic object will accept any value of the correct type.

Since you have an `std::atomic<size_t>` then any value *or variable* that is (or can be implicitly converted to) a `size_t` can be used on the right-hand side of the assignment.

As for the `GetVal` issue, `std::atomic` have a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T) which will do the right thing, atomically fetch the value and give it to you for the return.

Another note regarding the `GetVal` function: It will only be the fetching of the value that will be atomic, the `return` of it will not be. So between the fetch and the actual `return` the value of `m_atomic_val` can change, but the old value will be returned.

Comment: TL:DR: `std::atomic` overloads `operator=` as a seq_cst `.store(val)`, and conversion to the underlying type as a seq_cst `.load()`.  (as you showed with links).  The text of your description in terms of magic that happens on assignment or read also covers C11 `_Atomic size_t` which works the same way, with the magic happening inside the compiler, not a library template class.